# Event control on PDFs using Browser Helper Object

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, atl, dhtml, bho

i am new to Browser helper object i got the below link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C  which helps me to understand BHO but using this how can i acheive --in internet explorer when i open a PDFs file it has to throw an event and i need to catch it and find what extension it is trying to open and if its is PDFs then raise a popup message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IObjectWithSite::SetSite() implementation find and [hook a sink object to the DWebBrowserEvents2 connection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/08c0b48f-a2a3-4f71-beb2-3db9645b4561) point of the browser object passed into the SetSite function. Now in your event sink's IDispatch::Invoke implementation check if the URL parameter is a string ends with PDF.

If you do not want to show the PDF at all, you probably want to consider [handling the PDF MIME type by yourself.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148%28VS.85%29.aspx)